# Multiple meta queries but arrange by specific meta value order

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

Im working on a function which gets me lawyers based on criteria. The function works fine. Recently I added a meta key called `'is_endorsed'`. The value can be either `'1'` or `'0'`.

I need to bring endorsed user on top of results. Since we applied endorsement feature. Some members are set to `'1'`, and some are set to `'0'`. And most of them don't even have `'is_endorsed'` meta key in their `wp_usermeta` table.

The following code is working without endorsement filter. I've tried every possible modifications I knew, now its taking on my nerves. Please have a look and give me some tips.

```
function find_lawyer( $country = '', $state = '', $city = '' ) {
    $meta_query = array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'user_locations',
            'compare' => '!=',
            'value'   => ''
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'is_published',
            'compare' => '=',
            'value'   => '1'
        ),
    );

    if ( $country ) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => 'user_locations',
            'compare' => 'REGEXP',
            'value'   => '([\w|]*)country:' . $country . '([\w|]*)'
        );
    }

    if ( $state ) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => 'user_locations',
            'compare' => 'REGEXP',
            'value'   => '([\w|]*)state:' . $state . '([\w|]*)'
        );
    }

    if ( $city ) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => 'user_locations',
            'compare' => 'REGEXP',
            'value'   => '([\w|]*)city:' . $city . '([\w|]*)'
        );
    }

    $users_query = new WP_User_Query( array(
        'role'       => 'lawyer',
        'meta_query' => $meta_query
    ) );


    return $users_query->get_results();
}
```

And here is what I've tried. It gives me only users having `'is_endorsed' = '1'`.

```
function find_lawyer( $country = '', $state = '', $city = '' ) {
    $meta_query = array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'user_locations',
            'compare' => '!=',
            'value'   => ''
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'is_published',
            'compare' => '=',
            'value'   => '1'
        ),
        array( 
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array( 
                'key' => 'is_endorsed',
                'value' => '1',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ),
            array( 
                'key' => 'is_endorsed',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )             
        )

    ); // And so on...

    $users_query = new WP_User_Query( array(
        'role'       => 'lawyer',
        'meta_query' => $meta_query,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    ) );


    return $users_query->get_results();
}
```